# WinDBG conditional breakpoint based on string arguments

Tags: c, windbg

I want to set a conditional breakpoint when the value of the 4th argument is equal to "abc".

```
void FunctionA(char* a, char* b, char* c, char* d)
{
`enter code here`//some code here
}
```

I use the following command but it doesn't work. Could you help?

```
bp app!FunctionA "as /mu ${/v:MyAlias} poi(d);.block{.if ($spat(\"${MyAlias}\", \"abc\") == 0)  { } .else { gc } }"
```

Note: app.exe is my application name.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Does it break or not? Does it execute the command or not? Does it continue in wrong cases? Does it set the alias or not? Is there an error message?

Comment: Thanks for asking, Thomas. It doesn't break.

Comment: Sorry, I meant it always break. This is not expected.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29372648/480982

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot use **/mu** on **char ***  /mu is for **null terminated unicode string** not **ascii string**  for ascii string **use /ma**

I assume you have descriptive argument names and not an argument like **d** 
which would obviously clash with **0xd aka 0n13**
 **is d a number , string or symbol ??**

what would **poi(d)** resolve to in your case is it **poi(0x13)** which obviously is a bad de-referance
or a **local symbol** illogically named d ??

also alias is not interpreted when you break 
when using alias you should always stuff them in a script file and execute 
the script file on each break

here is an example of a  script file

```
as /ma ${/v:MyAlias} poi(k)
.block {
    r $t0 = $spat("${MyAlias}" , "tiger")
    .printf "%x\t${MyAlias}\n" , @$t0 
    .if(@$t0 != 1) {gc}
}
```

here is code on which this is operated comipled in debug mode with optimizations turned off
in release mode compiler will be smart enough to inline the printf() call

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //msvc _countof
void func(char* h,char* i,char* j,char* k ) {
    printf( "%s %s %s %s\n" ,h,i,j,k );
    return;
}
int main(void) {
    char* foo[] = {"goat","dog","sheep","cat","lion","tiger",0,"vampire"};
    for(int x=0;x<_countof(foo);x++) {
        func("this" , "is" , "a" , foo[x]);
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

usage

windbg app.exe

set the break and run
keep in mind this or any script that uses alias will fail on
evaluating the null entry before **char * vampire**
if you want to break on **"vampire"** you may need to improvise without using alias at all

```
0:000> bl
0:000> bp strbp!func "$$>a< strbpcond.txt"
0:000> bl
 0 e 00171260     0001 (0001)  0:**** strbp!func "$$>a< strbpcond.txt"
0:000> g
ModLoad: 72670000 72673000   C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.DLL
0   goat
0   dog
0   sheep
0   cat
0   lion
1   tiger
eax=00000005 ebx=7ffd7000 ecx=00000005 edx=001ac1e0 esi=001b6678 edi=001b667c
eip=00171260 esp=002bfa54 ebp=002bfa90 iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz ac po cy
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000293
strbp!func:
00171260 55              push    ebp
0:000> dv
              h = 0x001ac1f8 "this"
              i = 0x001ac1f4 "is"
              j = 0x001ac1f0 "a"
              k = 0x001ac1e0 "tiger"
```

Comment: Thanks blabb! I got some hints from your answer although I have some problems when following your steps. "$$>a< strbpcond.txt" doesn't work in my windbg.

Comment: Finally, I got this work! Thanks a lot! I need to place the script file in the folder of windbg.

Comment: No that is not the requirement you can place it in any folder rtfm is kinda frowned upon here so i wouldn't suggest it but will have to ask you to read the fantastic, fabulous, fine , forsaken,.........., manual and maybe comment back what is expected

Comment: I don't know what "alias is not interpreted when you break when using alias you should always stuff them in a script file and execute the script file on each break" even means, but my aliases are interpreted just fine when I use them in conditional breakpoints. Here's one I'm using now `bu KERNELBASE!RegSetValueExW "as /mu RegVal poi(@esp+8); .block { .if ($scmp(\"${RegVal}\",\"FooBar\") != 0) { gc; } }; ad RegVal;"` Works marvelously.